# I can't get the anime list from Kitsu Api with retrofit

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit

I get this error: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 10 path $.data

https://kitsu.io/api/edge/anime

RetroService retroService = RetroInstance.getRetrofit().create(RetroService.class);

```
public void makeApiCall() {
    Call<Animes> call = retroService.getAnimes();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Animes>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Animes> call, Response<Animes> response) {
            Log.d("Result", response.body().getData().getAttributes().getCanonicalTitle());

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Animes> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

@GET("anime")

````
```Call<Animes> getAnimes(); ```
````

My POJO classes:

```
    @Expose
    private Data data;

    /**
     * No args constructor for use in serialization
     *
     */
    public Animes() {
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param data
     */
    public Animes(Data data) {
        super();
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Data getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }



public class Data {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    private String type;
    @SerializedName("attributes")
    @Expose
    private Attributes attributes;


    //With  getter and setters and constructor

public class Attributes {
    @SerializedName("synopsis")
    @Expose
    private String synopsis;
    @SerializedName("canonicalTitle")
    @Expose
    private String canonicalTitle;
    @SerializedName("startDate")
    @Expose
    private String startDate;
    @SerializedName("endDate")
    @Expose
    private String endDate;
    @SerializedName("ratingRank")
    @Expose
    private Integer ratingRank;
    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private String status;
    @SerializedName("episodeCount")
    @Expose
    private Integer episodeCount;
    @SerializedName("youtubeVideoId")
    @Expose
    private String youtubeVideoId;
//With  getter and setters and constructor
```

Comment: when asking a json related question, could you also please include the json you'll receive (in your question, as text) - it just helps others out

Comment: it is linked in question

Comment: @snachmsm sure, but that doesn't help if the json from the link changes and not everyone wants to click on external links, that's annoying

Answer (score 0):

basically `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY` means that you have tried to parse single object (`Animes`), while there is no single object in JSON, it is an array (root)

don't know how your `RetroInstance` and `RetroService` works, but this:

```
Call<Animes> call = ...
```

should probably be

```
Call<ArrayList<Data>> call = ...
```

Comment: i tried to do that but the error changes to : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: RetroInstance: 
    private static Retrofit retrofit;

    public static Retrofit getRetrofit() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://kitsu.io/api/edge/")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }